# ¿Consulta mysql de cumpleaños a PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo mi siguiente consulta en mysql:`select * from employe where month(f_nac)=month(NOW())`

Obtengo los cumpleaños de este mes, sin embargo quiero pasar esta consulta a mi controller en PHP.

```
public function index()
{

    $cumpleaños = DB::table('employe')

        ->select('employe.*',
        'fech_nac')   

        ->where('month(f_nac)=month(NOW())')    

        ->get();

    return response()->json($cumpleaños);
}
```

Pero no obtengo resultado alguno.
Espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: por favor cuando tengas dudas debes ser mas claro y mas detallado con tu contexto (framework,lenguaje,contexto,etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

por la sintaxis asumo que es laravel

laravel tiene un función para colocar consultas raw ,para consultar por el mes quedando tu consulta así

```
    $cumpleaños = DB::table('employe')   
    ->whereraw('month(f_nac)=month(NOW())')    
    ->select('employe.*')
    ->get();
```

la fecha de nacimiento asumo tambien que corresponde a la misma tabla así que no es necesario nuevamente al usar 'employe.*'

otra manera seria asi:

```
     $mes = date('m');

     $cumpleaños = DB::table('employe')   
    ->wheremonth('f_nac',$mes)    
    ->select('employe.*')
    ->get();
```